# How to kill an execvp process

Tags: c, execvp

In a C program, I am using `execvp()` to create a netcat listener. When the program terminates, I would like to kill the listener. For example:

```
int main(){
  char *listener[] = {
    "/bin/bash",
    "-c",
    "nc -l 1338 > text.tar",
     NULL
   };
   execvp(listener[0], listener);
   return 0;
}
```

I would like to kill this netcat process right before the program terminates. However, I am looking at this code and thinking that maybe the program will terminate before the netcat listener receives any data. Maybe I could issue a wait command.

I guess it boils down to two questions:

- How can I kill the execvp proccess?
- Do I need a `wait()` call to give netcat some time?

Comment: maybe duplicate of https://serverfault.com/questions/512722/automatically-close-netcat-connection

Comment: @ymonad, I would like to open a netcat listener, have a client send over some data and save it on the server as a tar, and then close the listner

Comment: Yes. I mean that you can give `-c` or `-q` (depends on netcat variation) to `nc`, and send `EOF` from client when transfer is done. Do you have any reason that you cannot use this option?

Comment: Your program doesn't terminate. Do you know what execvp does?

Comment: After the `execvp()`, you program is no longer running and the process is running `nc`. The process won’t terminate until `nc` exits, whether if its own volition or as a result of a signal from another process. There is no opportunity to wait in your code.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, what would I need to do in order to not have the execvp replace my current proccess. I would like them to run concurrently.

Comment: Use `fork()` and have the child replace itself with `execvp()`.  Whenever you use any of the `exec*()` family of functions, the object is to replace the current process with a different running program (but with the same PID — process ID).  The only time an `exec*()` function returns is if it fails.  If it succeeds, there's a different program running in place of the current one (possibly the same program if you choose to run the same program, but it restarts from the beginning).  See the answer for how to do it if you want a process around to supervise `nc`.

Answer (score 3):

The `exec` functions family only returns when there is an error (i.e. the program could not be executed).

So you have to `fork()` first and keep track of the pid. But if you want to kill the child process just before the main program ends, it will likely have  no time to do anything.

Here we give 10 seconds to the child process before killing it

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>

#define TIME 10

int main(){
  char *listener[] = {
    "/bin/bash",
    "-c",
    "nc -l 1338 > text.tar",
     NULL
   };
   pid_t pid = fork();
   if ( ! pid) { // child
      execvp(listener[0], listener);
      // doesn't return (check error maybe)
   }
   printf("Waiting for %d seconds...\n", TIME);
   sleep(TIME);
   kill(pid, SIGTERM); 
   return 0;
}
```

The `SIGTERM` signal is used (or use `SIGINT`, like <kbd>Control-C</kbd>), check the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) to choose another one if necessary. `SIGKILL` is the "strongest" (not catchable by the child).

Comment: Control-C sends `SIGINT`, not `SIGQUIT`. Generally you use `SIGTERM` if you want to kill something politely. If you really want to kill something but want to try politeness, the standard way is to send `SIGTERM`, wait a couple seconds, and if the process still exists send `SIGKILL`.

Comment: Thanks, didn't remember for sure which is ^C ... since the man page gives number 3 to QUIT, I did the wrong choice..

Comment: I'm not sure if signals were mapped that way in the past, but it doesn't work that way now. For example, ^D is EOF, which isn't a signal at all, instead of `SIGILL`, which would make the program think it tried to run an illegal instruction.